# Divs align top edge

Tags: html, css

I set up a simple layout with some `divs` and filled them with an image each with different sizes. Surprisingly, they all aligned at the bottom of their images.
The `divs` are all exactly the same size and I want them to appear evenly next to each other:
[image: divs]

How can I achieve this?
You can find an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/v7yspc6q/

Those are my codes:

HTML code:

```
<div class="col">Abc
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/">
</div>
<div class="col">Def
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/800/600/">
</div>
<div class="col">Ghi
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/1000/900/">
</div>
<div class="col">Jkl
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/800/">
</div>
```

CSS code:

```
div {
    border: 1px solid;
}
.col {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 200px;
}
.col img {
    max-width: 95%;
    max-height: 95%;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you're using `inline-block` on the columns, you need to define the vertical alignment:

```
.col {
  vertical-align:top;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fuhkq1xh/1/)

Answer (score 0):

is this what you are looking for:
add overflow:auto to the column div to hide the different sizes of images inside the div:

```
.col {
display: inline-block;
width: 100px;
height: 200px;
overflow:auto;
```

}

Fiddle[working example](http://jsfiddle.net/v7yspc6q/1/)